# How can I calculate the union of multiple PostgreSQL arrays in a window?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a `student_changes` table which acts as an append-only ledger recording changes done to a `students` table. Each student has three attributes: first name, last name and birth year. Since not every change done to a student touches all fields, a dedicated `changes` column keeps track of the column names which were touched:

```sql
CREATE TABLE student_changes(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  inserted_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL,
  student_id INTEGER REFERENCES students(id) NOT NULL,
  first_name TEXT,
  last_name TEXT,
  birth_year INTEGER,
  changes TEXT[] NOT NULL CHECK (changes <@ '{first_name,last_name,birth_year}')
);
```

Here's a sample ledger:

```
 id |          inserted_at          | student_id | first_name | last_name | birth_year |        changes
----+-------------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------------------
  1 | 2023-02-23 14:47:58.431597+01 |          1 | Bobby      | Redford   |            | {first_name,last_name}
  2 | 2023-02-23 14:48:45.434176+01 |          1 |            |           |            | {last_name}
  4 | 2023-02-23 14:49:39.861268+01 |          2 |            |           |       1945 | {birth_year}
  5 | 2023-02-23 14:51:23.490387+01 |          1 |            | De Niro   |       1943 | {last_name,birth_year}
```

First, the first and last name of student 1 is changed to 'Bobby Redford'. Then, the last name of student 1 was changed to NULL (i.e. cleared). After that, student 2 was updated - the birth year was set to 1945. Finally, another update to student 1 was done, setting both the last name and the birth year.

I'd now like to define a view which "collapses" these changes such that in the output table, there is one row per student which indicates all the accumulated changes with more recent changes overwriting earlier changes. E.g. for the above input, I'd like to get

```
 student_id | first_name | last_name | birth_year |        changes
------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------------------
          1 | Bobby      | De Niro   |       1943 | {first_name,last_name,birth_year}
          2 |            |           |       1945 | {birth_year}
```

I mostly have this working by partitioning the input table on the `student_id` and then ordering each window:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (student_id)
    student_id,
    FIRST_VALUE(first_name) OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY (
        CASE WHEN 'first_name' = ANY(changes) THEN inserted_at END
    ) DESC NULLS LAST) AS first_name,
    FIRST_VALUE(last_name) OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY (
        CASE WHEN 'last_name' = ANY(changes) THEN inserted_at END
    ) DESC NULLS LAST) AS last_name,
    FIRST_VALUE(birth_year) OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY (
        CASE WHEN 'birth_year' = ANY(changes) THEN inserted_at END
    ) DESC NULLS LAST) AS birth_year
FROM student_changes;
```

This gives

```
 student_id | first_name | last_name | birth_year
------------+------------+-----------+------------
          1 | Bobby      | De Niro   |       1943
          2 |            |           |       1945
```

...but what I can't seem to figure out is how to compute the *union* of the `changes` arrays in each window.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question in that it doesn't offer a way to calculate the union of arrays in a window, but it does address the issue by joining the query given in the question with a query which calculates the array of changed fields per student:

```sql
WITH changed_fields AS (
    SELECT student_id,
    ARRAY_AGG(changes) changes
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
          student_id,
          UNNEST(changes) changes
          FROM student_changes) foo
    GROUP BY student_id
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (student_id)
    change.student_id,
    FIRST_VALUE(change.first_name) OVER (PARTITION BY change.student_id ORDER BY (
        CASE WHEN 'first_name' = ANY(change.changes) THEN inserted_at END
    ) DESC NULLS LAST) AS first_name,
    FIRST_VALUE(change.last_name) OVER (PARTITION BY change.student_id ORDER BY (
        CASE WHEN 'last_name' = ANY(change.changes) THEN inserted_at END
    ) DESC NULLS LAST) AS last_name,
    FIRST_VALUE(change.birth_year) OVER (PARTITION BY change.student_id ORDER BY (
        CASE WHEN 'birth_year' = ANY(change.changes) THEN inserted_at END
    ) DESC NULLS LAST) AS birth_year,
    fields.changes
FROM student_changes change
JOIN changed_fields fields ON fields.student_id = change.student_id
```